# What is the shortcut for confirming dialogs on Mac?

Tags: keyboard, macos, shortcut, dialog

I have a MacBook Pro 2015 with macOS Sierra 10.12.4 installed. I have a question about confirming dialogs.

I use WebStorm from JetBrains to write code. After some actions I can open Commit dialog. By the way the commit dialog opens with <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> shortcut. Here is this dialog:

[image]

I write some text and after that I need to press the Commit button (submit form).

**The problem:** I can't do this with a shortcut. I tried <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>. I assumed this would work, because submitting this dialog (and any other dialog like this, not only in this programm) is done by <kbd>control</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>, so I assumed on Mac it must be <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>enter</kbd>.

It is not only with this dialog, it also doesn't work in other applications either.

What is the hotkey to confirm dialogs on Mac?

Comment: Is this a Java application?

Comment: Yes it is Java app

Comment: Given that the button label starts with a C, you could try `Command` + `C`. Since it is in fact a drop-down menu and not a single-click button I would expect the menu to appear. Unless of course the Cancel button is in the way, because it too starts with a C, which is rather inconvenient.

Answer (score 8):

In general in macOS, you can select the default dialog button (highlighted blue) with Enter.

[image]

Enter selects the button on the right.

If you have All Controls enabled in System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts, then a blue outline can be moved around controls using ⇥ and ⇧⇥, with Space used to confirm. In the screenshot, Space selects the button on the left.

---

However, specifically for this question you are referring to IntelliJ. They have a history of not following Apple HIG and there does not appear to be a keyboard shortcut to press the Commit button on that window.

> Click this button to commit the selected files, or hover your mouse over this button to […]

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/commit-changes-dialog.html